# CocoaPods: Updated pre_install syntax?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm just now updating to CocoaPods 0.38.2 (or trying to) and have run into an issue with my pre_install hook that removes unwanted localizations. I've read through the [CocoaPods update documentation](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.38/) but after converting my `pods` to `pods_targets` I'm still getting an error: 
`undefined method 'root' for <Pod::PodTarget name=Alamofire >:Pod::PodTarget`
I don't see a replacement for root in the new `PodTarget` definition.

Here's the original hook:

```
pre_install do |installer|

  supported_locales = ['base', 'en']

  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    # remove unused localizations
    %x[ find "#{pod.root}" -name '*.lproj' ].split.each do |bundle|
      if (!supported_locales.include?(File.basename(bundle, ".lproj").downcase))
        # puts "Removing #{bundle}"
        FileUtils.rm_rf(bundle)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit/pull/188/files?short_path=04c6e90) solution, by modifying the `supported_locales` array to match your supported locales :

```
pre_install do |installer|
    supported_locales = ['base', 'da', 'en']

    Dir.glob(File.join(installer.sandbox.pod_dir('FormatterKit'), '**', '*.lproj')).each do |bundle|
        if (!supported_locales.include?(File.basename(bundle, ".lproj").downcase))
            puts "Removing #{bundle}"
            FileUtils.rm_rf(bundle)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to otaran on GitHub, I'm not sure how I missed your PR!